# OSError when reading 0x000000000000000C (Maxl DLL)

Tags: python, essbase

I'm trying to connect to Essbase using Maxl DLL but I'm getting an error. I think this error has to do with ctype, but I'm quite not sure how to find the root cause and fix this. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
Using Maxl DLL in C:\ORACLE\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\common\EssbaseRTC-64\11.1.2.0\bin\essmaxlu.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-c96d45911659>", line 42, in <module>
    eh = esss.connect("userID", "password", "123.123.123.123")

  File "C:\Python3\Lib\Essbase.py", line 220, in connect
    self.sts = self.maxl.MaxLSessionCreate(c_char_p(host.encode('utf-8')), c_char_p(user.encode('utf-8')), c_char_p(password.encode('utf-8')), byref(self.ssnInit), byref(self.sid))

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000000C
```

Here's what I have:

```
def connect(self, user, password, host='localhost'):
    self.sid = c_ushort(0)
    self.ssnInit = maxl_ssninit_t()
    self.sts = self.maxl.MaxLSessionCreate(c_char_p(host.encode('utf-8')), c_char_p(user.encode('utf-8')), c_char_p(password.encode('utf-8')), byref(self.ssnInit), byref(self.sid))
    self.user = user
    self.numFlds = 0
    self.bMdxQuery = 0
```

Comment: Some other essbasepy users have experienced that error in the past and were able to fix it by making sure to use Python 3 64-bit. That said, there have still beeb some issues depending on the Essbase version. Are you trying to connect to Essbase 11.1.2.4 or an earlier version? There is a fairly extensive thread at https://github.com/jasonwjones/essbasepy/issues/6 going over the issue.